# How to get your table boards (borders?) to show on email blast in Civi?

Tags: civimail

We are sending out an email with a table in the body of the email through the CIVI email; the boards of the table are not showing up in the draft.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using Mosaico or CiviMail core tool? Is it an e-mailing campaign or an e-mail template send individually? In a 'transactional' e-mail you should be able to use tables, in an e-mailing campaign I would recommend avoiding fancy templating.